# Building a REST API to publish a website to users domain

Tags: php, ajax, web-services, rest

**Use Case:** I am working on an application where user can build his own html template and publish it to his domain by selecting one. He can use different components to do this.

**Issue:** I want to transfer the pages build by the user from my domain to his created domain. Something similar to what is done [here](http://app.imcreator.com/edit). Now currently in the prototye, what I do is write the content to a file (*a `.html` file using ajax request*) then make an FTP connection to the users domain (*possible beacuse domains are created dynamically by the application*) and transfer the files to his domain.

This, I believe, cannot be the right way and I would like to build it around a REST service which would make it flexible and also secure.

**Research:** I went through the web and found some website handle this very well ([like the one mentioned above](http://app.imcreator.com/edit)) and believe they have built it as a service. Am I on the ?

I would like suggestions and the possibilities so I can move forward. I am using PHP on the server side and javascript on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see some possible features to add safety to your services :

1. Check the source IP from the request, and only allow your servers to make the REST calls.
2. add `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` with the list of the possible domains to make the calls, instead of the *.
3. add security tokens related to the caller machine IP address, that would work as a password for the machine.
4. send all the data using post instead of get.

To update the page, I would go this way :

1. keep the data in the database, on server 1
2. add a page that reads from the database the content of the page based on a domain parameter
3. on the domain page call server 1 with the domain parameter to get the contents

Comment: Thank you for the response!Yes I have taken care of the above,but I am not happy with the `FTP` I use to transfer files.I want a REST api (may be) to do it for me.Now its just a function and can you if possible have a look at the link,how they do it?Sorry if it takes your valuable time,but that might make clear how I want it to be done!

Comment: I believe what you can do is for each domain, you have the same page that based on the url request you make a call to your server #2 that manages the content.

Comment: did you think about saving the pages in the database ? that would make things very easier :)

Comment: I do save them to the database as I have a auto save feature for saving the page.But when I transfer I need to write it somewhere and then move the files becoz I don't have a DB connection on the users domain. :P

Comment: add my comments to the answer

Comment: I did not get you exactly,can you please elaborate a bit!

Comment: Do you think what you suggested can be built around a REST API?I don't have much knowledge about it but,it works around HTTP requests like GET,POST etc as per my study.Can I use it here?

Comment: yes you can use there, but make sure to add a token or something to restrict access to the services,